# Discussion around functionpointers in array of structs. What are good practises?

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

is there a more compact way for using function pointers inside a `struct` ?

Do I really need to type defining the function pointer? I tried without but received type errors. Are there any hazards, or anything that I've done that is against good code practice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void lineFunc(int* a)
{
    int x1 = a[0];
    int y1 = a[1];
    int x2 = a[2];
    int y2 = a[3];

   double length = sqrtf( pow( (x1-x2),2 )+ pow((y1-y2),2) );
   printf("%f\n", length);
}

void areaFunc(int* a)
{
   int base = a[0];
   int height = a[1];
   int area = base*height;
   printf("%d",area);
}

typedef   void (*Operation)(int* a );
typedef struct CALC_TYPE
{
   Operation  opt
} CALC;


int main()
{

    int lineArg[4] = {1 , 2, 3, 4}; //x1, y1, x2, y2
    int areaArg[2] = {5,10};    // base, height

    void (*lineCalc)(int*);
    void (*areaCalc)(int*);

   lineCalc = lineFunc;
   areaCalc = areaFunc;

   CALC line;
   CALC area;
   CALC* cmdArray = calloc(2,sizeof(CALC));


  line.opt = lineFunc;
  area.opt = areaFunc;

  cmdArray[0]=line;
  cmdArray[1]=area;

  cmdArray[0].opt(lineArg);
  cmdArray[1].opt(areaArg);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you get errors, always tell us what errors you receive.

Comment: `Operation  opt` --> `Operation  opt;`

Comment: Always post compilable code. See [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

> is there a more compact way for using function pointers inside a struct ?

No.

> Do I really need to type defining the function pointer?

No, but it makes your code much more readable because the notation for function pointers is arcane.  You could have instead written.

```
typedef struct CALC_TYPE
{
    void (*opt) (int*);
} CALC;
```

> Are there any hazards, or anything that I've done that is against good code practice?

Not really.  Making a struct that only contains 1 thing is questionable, but it's obviously a learning exercise.

Answer (score 3):

The typedef Operation and some variables are useless. The struct too but If I've understood you, you want to keep it. So here is a more compacte way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // calloc

void lineFunc(int* a)
{
   // ...
}

void areaFunc(int* a)
{
   // ...
}

typedef struct CALC_TYPE
{
   void (*opt)(int *a);
} CALC;

int main()
{
   int lineArg[4] = {1 , 2, 3, 4}; //x1, y1, x2, y2
   int areaArg[2] = {5,10};    // base, height

   CALC *cmdArray = calloc(2, sizeof(CALC));

   cmdArray[0].opt = lineFunc;
   cmdArray[1].opt = areaFunc;

   cmdArray[0].opt(lineArg);
   cmdArray[1].opt(areaArg);

   free(cmdArray); // 1 malloc/calloc => 1 free

   return 0;

}
```

EDIT:

> Are there any hazards, or anything that I've done that is against good
>   code practice?

- Include stdlib.h to use calloc
- Don't forget to free dynamically allocated memory
- Why pow then sqrtf then store in double ? Use sqrt instead
- You could avoid the use of a struct here

Comment: As far as I can see, this is basically the same answer as your first one. You also seem to like code-only answers. Care to explain (even briefly) what you suggest in plain text? Otherwise, these answers aren't really helpful, I'm afraid.

Comment: Indeed I have posted a first answer without the struct but I've understood later that the struct should be kept. This new version keeps it. And you're right about the minimum effort of explanation even with a small code. I have edited my post to take your remark into account.

Comment: Thanks. The list at the bottom makes it much easier to see what you changed.

Answer (score 1):

***One additional point*** that I did not see in the other answers concerns a benefit of struct usage: *function prototype stability*.  Even if a struct starts out with a single variable, future requirements for the struct may force more variables to be added.  Because of the way struct variables are passed as arguments, prototype's of functions written to use the original single single variable struct, will not be broken when additional variables are added.

For example, your struct can be defined as:

```
typedef struct CALC_TYPE
{
   Operation  opt
} CALC;
```

Or:

```
typedef struct CALC_TYPE
{
   Operation  opt       
   int a;
   float b;
} CALC;
```

Without forcing change to a function that calls it.:

```
void func(CALC *c)
{
    ...
}
```

It's a great way to allow changes to the number of items that need to be passed as data without changing the argument list.

Using a modification of your area function, consider the following struct that was initially designed to support area measurements:

```
typedef struct
{
    int length;
    int width;
}DIM;

int areaFunc(DIM *d)
{
   return d->length*d->width*d
}
```

Later a requirement for the struct to support volume forces the addition of a variable:

```
typedef struct
{
    int length;
    int width;
    int height;
}DIM;
```

Adding the new variable to the struct does not break the existing `areaFunc()`, but also supports the new function:

```
int volumeFunc(DIM *d)
{
   return d->length*d->width*d->height;
}
```